# SoapUI generates unexpected prefixes

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

As a part of a project that I'm working on, my .NET code must parse a WSDL file, and then compare the parsed Soap web request to what the SoapUI app will output with the exact same WSDL file. This is to see if the web service was altered without our knowledge.

So this means I have to get the XML namespace prefixes correct with the .NET code, even though I realize namespace prefixes are of little importance in the grand scheme of things. So, does anyone know how the SoapUI app generates namespace prefixes? I am seeing examples where the app takes the namespace and with it outputs 4 character long substrings, 3 character long substrings, and 3 character long substrings with a number concatenated to it. For example, the SoapUI app outputs this request from the WSDL (my comments are included):

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
     xmlns:**str**="www.string4field.acquirer.aci.com"
     xmlns:**str1**="www.string3field.acquirer.aci.com"
     xmlns:**str2**="www.string1field.acquirer.aci.com"
     xmlns:**smal**="www.smallintfield.acquirer.aci.com>

1. The first prefix **str** came from the first 3 characters of string4field.
2. The second the prefix, which would also be **str**, is derived from string3field, and is already taken, so SoapUI adds on a "1".
3. For the third prefix, which is again **str**, SoapUI concatenates a "2" to **str** since both **str** and **str1** were taken.
4. The last prefix, **smal**, is a 4 character string derived from smallintfield. And yes, that ends in an "l", not a "1". But why isn't it 3 characters long?

So my question is, does anyone know why the 4th namespace prefix is "**smal**" and not "**sma**"?
I am using SoapUI app (version 5.7.0).